# Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word assembly

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I have to do a word document programming in c#. Is there any way to access Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word assembly without installing Microsoft word? I tried to install Office Primary Interop Assemblies But it ask me install Microsoft Office package first.

Comment: I assume the Interop assemblies are wrappers over the OLE Automation interfaces. You still need the OLE Automation server (aka Microsoft Office) to instantiate something for the wrappers to wrap.

Comment: It is pretty pointless to attempt this, you cannot test your code.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the PIA Redistributable for whatever version of Office you are trying to work on?

The Office 2010 PIA redistributable, for example, does not list Office as a requirement (but of course that could be an error in the System Requirements section).

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=938fe8ad-583b-4bd7-a345-23250dc15855#SystemRequirements

Comment: Yes. The problem I didn't install Microsoft office package.( I am using Open Office instead) But I want to develop an application which has to deal with word files. I tried to install PIA-2003 and PIA-2007 but both requires Microsoft Office package to be installed in prior. I ll try PIA-2010 and let u know.

Comment: hmm... PIA-2010 also not installing. So Is the one and only solution is install the Microsoft Office package?

Comment: I got another error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085723/assembly-microsoft-office-interop-word-version-15-0-0-0-uses-microsoft-vbe-inte but I was resolve it with Office 2010 PIA so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

maybe its too late to answer... but for those who are looking for the same solution, [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) is the library Microsoft released and its used to work with office documents (doc, xls, ppt,...)

Answer (score 0):

As Dr TJ says, you could use [Open XML SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) for it.
We used Word.Interop but it halt sometimes, and it is not recommend for Microsoft, to use it as a server side document formatting, so Open XML SDK lets you creates word documents on DOCX and Open XML formats very easily.
It lets you going well with scability, confidence ( the files, if it is corrupted can be rebuild ), and another very fine characteristics.