# Assembly Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=15.0.0.0 uses Microsoft.Vbe.Interop, Version=15.0.0.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, office-interop

I just downloaded  MS Visual Studio 2010 solution and get that error.

> Error 1   Assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'  uses
>   'Microsoft.Vbe.Interop, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'  which has a higher version than
>   referenced assembly  'Microsoft.Vbe.Interop, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' 
>   c:\PROJECTS\UHelper\Assemblies\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll
>   AcceptService.Web

I have MS Office 2010 installed.
I have reference to local copy of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll within project.

Any clue how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I got this [page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type/34efcd57-e819-4a83-9cdd-501ab15b0971) that I assumed should be useful. But it was not. :(
Anyway I put that link so it **CAN** be useful for someone else.

Second point was to use advice that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327252/using-microsoft-office-interop-word-assembly)

So I navigated to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18249
And installed [Microsoft Office 2010 Primary Interop Assemblies Bootstrapper Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx).

And finally I deleted  `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll`  reference in the project and added another one

> Visual Studio installs these copies of PIAs to the following locations:
>   On the development computer: `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14` (or `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14` on 64-bit operating systems)
>   `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for
>   Office\PIA\Office15` (or `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15` on 64-bit operating systems)

And yeah!!! Error gone! :)