# Use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

In my project, I need to manipulate a .docx file. I was searching in Google and I found this dll: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. In my computer, I have Microsoft Office and it's ok but if I run my project in another computer without Microsoft Office installed (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll will go with project), will my program run?

Comment: @codroipo: I can't see where OP mentioned this being a website

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I don't *think* it will work. When you use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` you basic just command a word application to do the work, i.e. send it instructions. Without having Word installed you would have nothing to command

Comment: This question might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327252/using-microsoft-office-interop-word-assembly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` (and all other interop) will just work when Office is installed on that machine. It is a requirement to actually create the instance of Word.

Interop does start the Word executable and can't stand on its own.

It is also [discouraged to use Interop on a server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757).

Answer (score 1):

I concur with Patrick's answer.

If you need to manipulate a docx file on a machine without the Word application installed you can work directly with the file via the Office Open XML file format. This can be done with any tools that can work with Zip packages (a docx file is a zip package of the files that make up the document) and XML.

Microsoft provides the Open XML SDK for VB.NET and C# which makes things simpler. There's also an SDK for JavaScript.

You'll find more information at OpenXMLDeveloper.org.